# Exception Error Dialog

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

I wanted to know why on some computers when an unhandled exception occurs in .NET (C# or VB.NET application) why it shows different dialogs.

Eg, on some computers it shows similar to this:

[image: first example dialog]

While on the others, it shows like this:

[image: second example dialog]

I wanted to show it like on the second (Unhandled exception has occurred in your application) one in all systems that use my application for some specific purposes.

Please don't suggest to use global exception handler method.

Comment: @jgauffin its not only native app and .NET app. the first type of dialog occurs on some of my clients computer on my applications (offcourse coded in c#) while on others it shows 2nd type of dialog (jit) which i needed

Comment: Why would you so adamantly _not_ prefer to us a global exception handler for this type of thing? You could just create your own error dialog and design it as you like to your heart's content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what you marked as correct behavior can be controlled by enabling and disabling JIT (Just in time debuger).

Maybe this can help you out, or just set you on the right track: [MSDN: How to: Enable/Disable Just-In-Time Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kf6y2a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I am not suggesting anything but the practice is that the end user should ***never*** get this kind of exception especially with a stack trace.

Comment: Hello, but that's for the computer that have Visual Studio installed. Right? How would one get the same dialog in computers that does not have Visual Studio installed?

Comment: @WalterBoss You need to wrap the code that can throw errors in a try-catch block, and then display the info in a message box, or a custom form.

Comment: @Tibi, i know about that. But i wanted to know how to get this type of dialog for some specific reason

Comment: @Walter To be quite honest I am not sure if you need to have VS installed. [link] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6(v=vs.80).aspx [/link]
says "Just-In-Time debugging is a feature that launches the Visual Studio debugger automatically when a program, running outside Visual Studio, encounters a fatal err."
But it also states: "...use the registry editor to delete the following registry keys:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger
ON non-VS machine are there these keys?

Answer (score 1):

Some applications have JIT debugging enabled:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx

Specifically, in a .NET app.config you can add:

```
<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>
```